# Django show extra content in class based view with ForeignKey models

Tags: django, django-template-filters, generic-foreign-key

I'm trying to add extra content to Djangos Class-based view to the template

I have some models like this

```
class District(models.Model):
    district = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, unique=False, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.district


class Street(models.Model):
    street_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, unique=False, blank=True)
    district = models.ForeignKey(District, verbose_name=_('district'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    zone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.street_name


class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="author", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)   
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS, default=CREATED)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, unique=False, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, unique=False)
    street = models.ForeignKey(Street, verbose_name=_('street'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)


class ArticlesListView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Article
    paginate_by = 50
    context_object_name = "articles"
    permission_required = 'is_staff'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['Filter_name'] = Article.objects.order_by().values('name').distinct()
        context['Filter_user'] = Article.objects.order_by().values('user').distinct()
        return context


    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        return Article.objects.all()
```

And late in the template

```
{% for f in Filter_name %}
  <ul>
    <li>{{f.name}}</li>
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I display a list of the district names and a list of the author names in the template with ForeignKey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can try something like [that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set)

```
{% for item in model_1.foreign_model_set.all %}
    <h1>{{ item }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this show only the values from the loaded html and not all values from the database

Comment: add them to queryset

Comment: Thanks its working. One more question, in the now filtered results, what is the easiest way to change the status with one button to all?

Comment: U need to write a new orm-query to that btn. Filtering and get/post requests are different.